# como hago el for para coger datos de una api en json de dos requests

Tags: python, json, api, script

en el endpoint de la instancia necesito la url de autenticación que es personal de cada instalación, esta la pongo mediante parámetros

```
parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', help='openstack api keystone url', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
user_url = args.url
```

teniendo estos dos puntos finales de una api, :

```
# solicitar url
req = {
"instancia": user_url + "/servidores".
"servidores": user_url + "/servidores/" + {id-instancia} + "/diagnostics"}
```

{id-instancia} es un dato json que sale en el primer endpoint : "instancia": user_url + "/servidores".

¿como obtengo el id de cada instancia y luego lo pongo en el segundo endpoint que lo necesito para ver las métricas detalladas y que me pinte un dato json del segundo (o entero) por cada id de la instancia?

Creo que sería crear una lista, y poner con un for en ella todos los ids de la instancia, y luego con otro for hacer una petición por cada id de la instancia.

para hacer lo primero he hecho esto :

```
for:
    result = requests.get(req["instance"], headers=headers)
    result_data = json.loads(result.content)
except Exception as e :
    print('0')
    sys.exit("\NError al solicitar %s, por favor compruebe la conectividad" %(req["instancia"],))

instance_id=[]

for data in result_data["instance"] :
    id_instance.append(data['id'])
```

que creo que está bien pero ¿cómo haría el segundo for?